# Issues on using VHDL module in verilog

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I'm having Synthesis errors on using a VHDL module in Verilog. The error message below says that the type of rd_ptr input in the VHDL module does not match the rd_ptr_integer variable in the verilog code.The compiler also gives this error for the pckt_size output variable.
Please help me on this.

The vhdl module entity is this

```
   entity packet_size is
    generic(
      fifo_MaxDepth:integer range 0 to 256:=16
      );
   port(
    fifo_tlast:in std_logic_vector(fifo_MaxDepth -1 downto 0);
    depth:in std_logic_vector(fifo_MaxDepth -1 downto 0);
    rd_ptr:in integer range 0 to fifo_MaxDepth - 1;
    pckt_size:out integer 
    );
     end packet_size;
```

The part of my verilog code that is the source of the error is this

```
 reg [WIDTH-1:0] queue [MAX_DEPTH - 1 : 0];
 reg [MAX_DEPTH_BITS - 1 : 0] rd_ptr;
 reg [MAX_DEPTH_BITS - 1 : 0] wr_ptr;
 reg [MAX_DEPTH_BITS : 0] depth;
 wire [MAX_DEPTH : 0]fifo_tlast_packet;
 wire [MAX_DEPTH_BITS - 1 : 0] rd_ptr_temp;
 integer packet_size_out;
 integer rd_ptr_integer;
 assign num_of_packets=depth;
 assign rd_ptr_temp=rd_ptr;
   // Sample the data
   //initialising the fifo_tlast_packet array for the packet_size module
   genvar    i;
   for (i=0;i<MAX_DEPTH;i=i+1) begin
    assign fifo_tlast_packet[i]=queue[i][0];
    end;
    //converting array to integer
    always @(rd_ptr_temp)
     begin
      rd_ptr_integer=rd_ptr_temp;
      end
      //adding the packet_size module for measuring the packet size of the first fifo data
    packet_size
     #(.fifo_MaxDepth(MAX_DEPTH) )
       packet1(
        .fifo_tlast(fifo_tlast_packet),
        .depth(depth),
        .rd_ptr(rd_ptr_integer),
        .pckt_size(packet_size_out)
        );
```

The errors shown in ISE Synthesis are here

```
  ERROR:HDLCompiler:440 - "K:/final project/codes/v3/small_fifo_v3.v" Line 69: Formal port rd_ptr of type integer does not match with actual type integer
  ERROR:HDLCompiler:440 - "K:/final project/codes/v3/small_fifo_v3.v" Line 70: Formal port pckt_size of type integer does not match with actual type integer
  ERROR:HDLCompiler:1654 - "K:/final project/codes/v3/small_fifo_v3.v" Line 64: Instantiating <packet1> from unknown module <packet_size>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `integer` does not match `integer` this looks like a tool issue with ISE rather than a problem with your design.

First I would eliminate the latter by verifying it in simulation : either ISIM (with some restrictions) or Modelsim should handle mixed designs.

Having confirmed the design, you need a workaround for the tools issue.

If you change the chosen FPGA to something like Spartan-3, ISE defaults to an older VHDL parser which handles some VHDL constructs better, with an "advanced" option touse the new parser instead. Try both... Of course if you need a newer FPGA this won't solve your problem but it may point closer to the problem ... see below.

Alternatively, Xilinx now offers a third VHDL parser in the form of Vivado - maybe this will solve the problem.

(If the problem actually lies on the Verilog side I'm afraid I can't help, if it was my job I'd re-write that little Verilog module in VHDL and be done with it).

If none of the above helps, then you will have to go against my [usual advice](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/188622/vhdl-converting-types-and-integer-substraction/188677?noredirect=1#comment389367_188677) and actually use std_logic_vector for the port, and whatever the Verilog equivalent is, and the appropriate type conversions to/from integer via (signed or unsigned) on either side.

Comment: I had to implement my design on a kintex 7 so I gone with your last advise and the error was solved.